# Transferring a modified file, via FTP, in safe mode?

Tags: php, ftp, safe-mode

I have a list of existing files that need to follow these steps:

1. Stored in a temporary file
2. Modified
3. Transferred to another server via FTP. All while the server is running in safe mode.

I can't use `tmpfile()`, because I still wouldn't be able to modify it, before sending it off.

Anyone come across this kind of problem and find a solution? Any ideas at all?

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is and what safe mode has to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Beforehand, create a temporary directory owned by the user under which PHP runs.

At run time, create a file in that directory.  Put some stuff into its contents.  Now you have your temporary file.  Finally, send it off via FTP.  No problem there.